# How to write this PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a SQL query that selects the first (based off smallest ID) quest an NPC has available.

If the user already has a quest from that NPC do not return that quest.

`Quests` table

```
id | npc     | name
---+---------+------------
 1 | NPC-1   | Kill an Ogre 
 2 | NPC-1   | Kill a Bear
 3 | NPC-2   | Kill a Cow
```

`quest_completions table` : if there's an entry in here it means the quest is in progress unless rewarded is set to true then it is fully done and rewarded and the next quest is available.

```
quest_name   |  rewarded   |  player_id
-------------+-------------+-----------
Kill an Ogre |   false     |      0
```

I want to return `[NPC-2]` because that is the only NPC with an available quest.

I can show you my SQL query but for some reason it isn't working. I'm not really sure how to debug it.

```
SELECT 
    npc
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         ON(npc) quests.npc,
         MIN(quests.id),
         quests.name
     FROM 
         quests
     LEFT JOIN 
         quest_completions ON quest_completions.quest_name = quests.name
      WHERE 
          (quest_completions.rewarded IS NULL
           OR quest_completions.rewarded = false)
          AND quest_completions.player_id = 5
      GROUP BY 
          npc, quests.name) a
WHERE 
    a.name NOT IN (SELECT quest_completions.quest_name
                   FROM quest_completions
                   LEFT JOIN quests ON quest_completions.quest_name = quests.name
                   WHERE rewarded = false);
```

**Edit**: I actually created a very detailed fiddle that includes test data and expected output https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNs4C1FCitLQqeDzMJg1xn/3

Comment: K, now second question, why is NPC-2 (id 3) the only quest available since there is no other entries on the quest_completion table for the other 2 quests of NPC-1? Shouldn't the quest "1 | NPC-1   | Kill an Ogre" be available since it is the smallest ID for that NPC and there is not an entry in quest_completion ?

Comment: `Kill an Ogre` is in quest_completion! So because there is an `NPC-1` quest in progress (rewarded=false) we dont want to return `NPC-1` in the result!

Comment: Ooh woops... I read the quests backwards... now I get it... let me see what I can do here

Comment: Last question which RDBMs (mysql, postgresql, oracle, etc) are you using and which version?

Comment: I am using postgres! Also here's a DB Fiddle with some data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNs4C1FCitLQqeDzMJg1xn/0

Comment: The problem I'm seeing here is that you don't have a NPC table, without that you need to figure out first all NPCs which makes the result query bigger. It is solvable but you sure should consider adding it... also, as a relational database, there should be proper foreign keys to make the relation between the tables clear and consistent, for instance, instead of relying on the quest name, quest_completion should have a column quest_id instead of quest_name. same for quests, it should have a column npc_id referring to a npc table.

Comment: I know I know. I'm not worried about that right now but I agree completely. I just want it to work..

Comment: @bezzoon your dbfiddle is for MySQL, but you've added the postgres tag to your question. Which is it? Also, your db fiddle has no data for queries

Comment: Postgres but can I use dbfiddle for postgres? I just really wanted to communicate the Schema

Comment: This is not a simple problem lol... both answers are giving wrong result when testing it...

Comment: yeah exactly. They're both wrong...

Comment: Alright I put more effort into the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNs4C1FCitLQqeDzMJg1xn/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after many tests I finally came up with a working solution.

Here is the query:

```
select npc, min(id) questId
  from quests q 
 where q.id not in (select q.id
               from quests q
              inner join quest_completions qc on q.name = qc.quest_name
              where player_id = 0
            )
  and q.npc not in (select q.npc
               from quests q
              inner join quest_completions qc on q.name = qc.quest_name
             where (qc.rewarded = false or qc.rewarded is null)
               and player_id = 0
            )
group by npc;
```

I had to think of excluding all in progress quest `quests` per NPC then any quest per player

Here is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddf7ZrFhdn9HpKWY4rdXs1/0

I've tested all sorts of combinations in my local environment.

Like:
case 1: Returns NPC-2, quest id 3

```
delete from quest_completions
insert into quest_completions values ('Kill an Ogre', false, 0);
```

case 2: Returns NPC-2, quest id 3

```
delete from quest_completions
insert into quest_completions values ('Kill a Bear', false, 0);
```

case 3: Returns NPC-1, quest id 1

```
delete from quest_completions
insert into quest_completions values ('Kill a Cow', false, 0);
```

case 4: Returns NPC-1/quest id 2 and NPC-2/quest id 3

```
delete from quest_completions
insert into quest_completions values ('Kill an Ogre', true, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct q.npc from quests q
where q.name not in (
select q.name from quests q
left join quest_completions qc on q.name = qc.quest_name and qc.player_id=0
where qc.rewarded=true);
```

I work with your fiddle. I think it's working... Take a try.

**Here is fiddle:**
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNs4C1FCitLQqeDzMJg1xn/7

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle. Your answer unfortunately doesn't work!

Comment: Ok.. I got it. but your fiddle example, quest name has some typo. quest id [4,5]'s name is not same with quest_completions table. Anyway I fix that have same quest_name and do test. I'll edit my answer.